# AWS ELB ingress - Accessing my app only works with NodePort

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have created a EKS Cluster and have a domain name from freenom. I created an ingress resources with host as my domain name.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: 2048-ingress
  name: 2048-ingress
  namespace: 2048-game
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mytestabcapp.tk
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-2048
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```

I can access the service on `myapptestabcapp.tk:32531` where 32531 is the node port! How can I make sure that the host can access it on just `myapptestabcapp.tk` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md` I was able to follow this and create a external-dns enabled with ALB.

Basically make sure to do the following:

- Create hosted zone
- Deploy external dns
- Deploy ingress (if you want to use ingress)
- Create a service

I also had a free domain created with freenom.com, which I was able to hookup to my service running on EKS.